# Homology group of mapping cylinder for map of degree m

Tags: algebraic-topology

Hatcher claims on p. 148 that $H_{n}(M_{f},S^{n})=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, where $f$ is a degree $m>1$ map of $S^{n}$, and $M_{f}$ is the associated mapping cylinder. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to be more specific about how you intended $S^n$ to embed in $M_f$.  I didn't look in Hatcher but I'm supposing it's the $S^n$ on the "0" end of the cylinder.  If it's the $S^n$ on the "1" end, then $H_n(M_f, S^n)$ is trivial.

Think about the long exact sequence in which relative homology fits:

$$
\cdots H_{n}(S^n) \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow}
H_{n}(M_f) \stackrel{\beta}{\longrightarrow}
H_{n}(M_f, S^n) \stackrel{\gamma}{\longrightarrow}
H_{n-1}(S^n) = 0
$$

One can see that $\beta$ is a surjection, so 
$$
H_n(M_f, S^n) = H_n(M_f) / \mathrm{im} (\alpha).
$$
Can you see how this proves your result?  Think about what $\alpha$ does to a generator of $H_n(S_n)$.